# How to remove hardcoded path in UserSettings?

Tags: unity, git

I would like to use Git for my Unity projects. I took the default .gitignore file that GitHub provides, but I noticed that it doesn't ignore the UserSettings folder. That wouldn't really be a big deal usually, but I noticed that the full project path is hardcoded in one of the files in that folder, specifically "UserSettings -> Layouts -> default-2021.dwlt" under "m_LastProjectPath".

I'm not a fan of that.

- Should I put the UserSettings folder into the .gitignore as well, or maybe just "default-2021.dwlt"?
- Is there perhaps a setting in Unity that removes m_LastProjectPath?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be ignored because, as you noticed, it's specific to each Unity user.
You can find details behind the reasoning here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/whats-the-usersettings-directory.754436/

I don't know why the gitignore generated on the github website is out of date. I usually go directly to the source repository to get an up to date gitignore. As of today it contains the "UserSettings" folder. https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore

Btw, if some folks need a little more detail on how to use it with Unity, I've written a blog post about that: https://crafty.creatiel.ca/blog/unity-gitignore-essentials

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add this line to your .gitignore file to ignore /UserSettings folder:

```
/[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really helpful. I already know how to add the folder to the .gitignore, that wasn't the point of my question. It's more about if I *should* add it to the .gitignore (pros and cons for example), and if the answer is "no", how to avoid having the full path inside the project files.

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html
This folder should be ignored, it can contains some data that is per user (like perforce connection settings, layouts etc..).
In older versions of Unity it was part of Library/EditorUserSettings.asset but Unity Technologies moved it to a separate folder since "people delete the library folder all the time" : https://forum.unity.com/threads/whats-the-usersettings-directory.754436/#post-5029937

Comment: I see now what the problem was and where the confusion stemmed from... I was wondering why GitHub offered a seemingly outdated .gitignore for Unity projects, and it seems like GitHub actually messed up. When you create a new project on GitHub and pick the Unity .gitignore from the dropdown, like I did, it gives you an old version. However, if you click the "Get latest from" link in that same .gitignore file, you'll *actually* get the latest version of the .gitignore - one that has UserSettings in it. So for whatever reason, GitHub gave me the wrong .gitignore all this time...